# Facebook iOS SDK for Xamarin gives a strange error message

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I´m trying to learn how to use the Facebook iOS SDK for Xamarin. Tried to make an really easy application that just logs you in and then display your name in a label. However I get this error message, that I don't find any information about on the internet. I also get this error message when I try to use some of the sample applications that comes with the SDK. The error message is below:

[image]

This is what i added in my ViewController, everything else is untouched from a standard project:

```
    private string [] ExtendedPermissions = new [] { "user_about_me", "public_profile", "read_stream"};
    FBLoginView loginView;
    IFBGraphPerson user;

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        loginView = new FBLoginView (ExtendedPermissions) {
            Frame = new RectangleF(85, 20, 151, 43)
        };

        loginView.FetchedUserInfo += (sender, e) => {
            user = e.User;
            LoginLabel.Text = user.GetName();
        };

        View.AddSubview (loginView);
    }
```

And this is in the AppDelegate:

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        FBSettings.DefaultAppID = FacebookAppId;
        FBSettings.DefaultDisplayName = DisplayName;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OpenUrl (UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        // We need to handle URLs by passing them to FBSession in order for SSO authentication
        // to work.
        return FBSession.ActiveSession.HandleOpenURL(url);
    }

    public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
    {
        // We need to properly handle activation of the application with regards to SSO
        // (e.g., returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching).
        FBSession.ActiveSession.HandleDidBecomeActive();
    }
```

If anyone have any idea what this error means, I would be really grateful!

Comment: I tested your code and everything went ok for me... can you share your version of Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.iOS? If you don't know where it is, click Xamarin Studio on the upper left conner->About Xamarin Studio->Show Details. Also which version of Facebook iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: i use Xamarin 5.0.1 and Facebook iOS SDK 3.19.0.1

Comment: mmm... which version of Xamarin.iOS you have installed?? I think you're out of date, I have Xamarin Studio 5.5.2 and Xamarin.iOS 8.2 on the stable channel. Check for updates, install them and try again.